# Why do carrots spoil so fast?

Tags: safety, vegetable

The carrots we buy from a supermarkets spoil very fast, albeit giving many consumers a false sense of preservability due to their structural rigidity. The answer extends to many other vegetables many of us eat:

[image: carrots- wikimedia]
 Larsinio (2006)- wikimedia, public domain, DOR 27/09/2012

The question is, **why do well aerated carrots spoil in the matter of days, at room temperature?**

**Things to consider**: a tuberous rhizome with rough and segmented skin / oxygen levels / levels of aeration / relatively high sugar content / differences in immediate microbiome / lack of possible synergies which the earth provides...the majority of antibiotics is extracted from soil microorganisms [{1}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq1YK.jpg),[{2}](http://benthamscience.com/open/tonutraj/articles/V005/107TONUTRAJ.pdf)....

Comment: Remember that tubers are designed for a relatively anaerobic environment. My guess is that what you are seeing is related to that. Oxidation perhaps? Aerobic bacteria gone wild?

Comment: I think carrot keeps long time in refrigerator. Why store it at room temp when optimal storing condition is refrigerator ?

Comment: @Andrei Initially I wanted to explain that in the post as well and include storage conditions. But I consider it best to just ask one question at a time. Regardless, did you have consistently success w. long-term fridge storage?

Comment: can you reference your declaration that carrots spoil fast please since I also think that it depends on a lot of factors like where it was grown, the kind of fertilizers used etc

Comment: Strange question...Carrots usually (>95% of the time) last for 1+ months for me in the fridge. I'd hardly say that's a quick rate of spoiling

Answer (score 3):

First we will take a look at the lines of resistance of a carrot. There are three

> **The skin** - The first line of resistance is the outer membrane or skin of the carrot and chemical compounds that are normally present
>   there. Two antifungal polyacetylenes, falcarinol and falcarindiol, and
>   an isocoumarin, 6-methoxymellein, are present in small amounts in a
>   normal carrot and present the first barrier in undamaged carrots.
>
> **Post Harvest** - If during harvest or post harvest handling this barrier is broken, the surface is punctured, scraped or sliced,
>   microorganisms may begin to grow. The carrot at this point begins a
>   wound healing process by accumulating suberin, a complex
>   polysaccharide, at the wound site. Along with suberin, lignin is also
>   accumulated. Suberisation is complete within 48 hours after wounding,
>   and lignification is complete within 168 hours of wounding..
>
> **Phytoalexin barrier** - The last and most important line of resistance is the phytoalexin barrier. Phytoalexins are chemicals
>   produced by plants that impart disease resistance in response to
>   mechanical injury, physiological stimuli or infection. Scopoletin, a
>   coumarin,and para-hydroxy benzoic acid, a phenol, are apparently early
>   arrivals on the scene but later disappear ([reference](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/Disease%20Response%20Mechanism.pdf)).

There are three enemies of carrot storage: wilt, re-growth and rot.

Some reasons for carrots rotting faster:

Many fruits and vegetables start to produce ethylene gas when they start to ripen. Some foods are extremely sensitive to ethylene gas which makes them rot faster ([reference](http://www.coreperformance.com/daily/nutrition/why-fresh-produce-goes-bad-so-fast.html)). I am guessing that you keep different vegetables close together. Maybe if you stored carrots separately, it might make them last a bit longer.

> Major post-harvest losses in carrots are due to Sclerotinia rot,
>   Botrytis rot, Bacterial soft rot (Erwinia) and Sour rot (Geotrichum).
>   Of these, Sclerotinia rot is the most prevalent.The Sclerotinia fungus
>   infects the carrot roots in the field through the crown. During
>   storage, the Sclerotinia fungus produces a white, cottony mycelium
>   which covers the roots. Infected roots are usually soft and watery ([reference](http://www5.agr.gc.ca/resources/prod/doc/pfra.../carrots-carottes_eng.pdf)).

There would definitely be more reasons but I am guessing that these are the major contributors to it rotting faster.